# natbib and aaai-named

Tags: natbib

I have to use [the `aaai-named` style](https://www.mackichan.com/products/shells/aaai-named.pdf).

I want to use it in Overleaf. I tried to use that `.bst` file and integrated it in that way:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aaai-named}

\begin{document}

  \citep{latexcompanion}

  \bibliography{references.bib}

\end{document}
```

This is working fine but

1. I want to use `biblatex` not `natbib`
2. The citations aren't integrated because I get only (author) instead [author, year] by doing `\cite()`, `\citep{}`, ...

Can anyone help to integrate that? Or does anyone knows a similar style which is supported by Overleaf?

Comment: `aaai-named` is a BibTeX style file (a `.bst` file) and can not be used together with `biblatex`. The style is compatible with `natbib`'s `authoryear` style, though. That style, however, must be loaded as `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` and not with the `style=prefix`. If `natbib` does not work for you, we need to see an example how exactly things fail. Please prepare an MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864

Comment: `\bibliography` needs the file *without* extension, so it should be `\bibliography{references}`. Though that is unlikely to be an issue. What does the entry `latexcompanion` in `references.bib` look like?

Comment: `@book{latexcompanion, 
    author        = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin},
    title         = {The \LaTeX\ Companion},
    year          = {1993},
    publisher     = {Addison-Wesley},
    location      = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}`

Comment: @moewe that isn't that problem anymore. thank you. The problem now is that the refenreces in the bibliography look like this: `Donald Knuth. Knuth: Computers and typesetting, 1984.` instead `[Knuth, 1984] Donald Knuth. Knuth: Computers and typesetting, 1984.`

Answer (score 2):

`biblatex` is not compatible with the `.bst` files used by BibTeX. So you can't use `biblatex` together with `aaai-named`. `aaai-named` is, however, compatible with `natbib` and so the following MWE works just fine for me.

`natbib`'s author-year modus is entered with the option `authoryear` *without* `style=` prefix. `natbib`'s `square` option gives you square brackets for your citation.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[authoryear,square]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{aaai-named}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{latexcompanion,
  author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach
               and Alexander Samarin},
  title     = {The \LaTeX\ Companion},
  year      = {1993},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\citep{latexcompanion}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: [Goossens et al., 1993]]

The command `\bibliography` takes the file name argument without file extension.

---

`natbib` does not show the author-year labels in the bibliography by default (presumably because they are normally redundant with author-year-compatible bibliography styles, but I admit that the fact that the year comes towards the end in `aaai-named` makes the label more attractive).

If you don't need `natbib`'s extended features you can use the following modifications of `\cite` that are suggested in the comments in `aaai-named.bst`

```
\documentclass{article}

\bibliographystyle{aaai-named}

\makeatletter
\let\@internalcite\cite
\def\cite{\def\citename##1{##1}\@internalcite}
\def\shortcite{\def\citename##1{}\@internalcite}
\def\@biblabel#1{\def\citename##1{##1}[#1]\hfill}
\makeatother

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{latexcompanion,
  author    = {Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach
               and Alexander Samarin},
  title     = {The \LaTeX\ Companion},
  year      = {1993},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Massachusetts}
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{latexcompanion}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. After I took a new Overleaf Document, I got it. I seems that the failure was in the references.bib which is normally bigger in that real project. But now, are you sure that the references shouldn't look like this: with that brackets [] in front of it ?:  `[Aamport, 1986] L[eslie] A. Aamport. The gnats and gnus document prepa- ration system. G-Animal's Journal, 41(7):73+, July 1986. This is a full ARTICLE entry.`  ?

Comment: @user182410 `natbib` does not display the citation labels in the bibliography again for `authoryear` styles. So it is kind of expected that you don't see the "[Aamport, 1986]". I couldn't find a quick way to make `natbib` show the label and I will only have time to investigate if that is possible tomorrow or the day after.

Comment: would be great ! thanks for your time, sorry for my mistake here , I couldn't now that there is a failure in my references.bib , I don't now where the failure is there .. next time i will do directly an MME.  thanks for you help !